# SQL Server rows into columns, limit rows,

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have been messing around with the pivot function but I am not sure it does what I want. I have a parent child relationship where a storage ticket can have multiple factors and values. I am quite happy to limit the number of results to a predefined number, I will go with two for this question.

Here is a simpler result set.

```
StorageTicketID FactorID    FactorValue
---------------------------------------
23               116        90
23               210        13.2
```

I don't think pivot works because there are a large number of possibilities for `FactorId` and I am not interested in creating a column named after each specific `FactorId`.

Here is what I came up with. It works but i am hoping there is a better way!

```
select 
    StorageTicketID,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by StorageTicketID) rownumber, 
    glfr.FactorID, glfr.FactorValue 
into 
    #temp1 
from 
    pgf_master.dbo.StorageTicket st  
join 
    PGF_Master.dbo.GrainLoadFactorResult glfr on glfr.ParentID = st.StorageTicketID
                                              and StorageTicketID = 23
                                              and glfr.ParentTypeId = 2

select 
    max(StorageTicketID) ID,
    (select factorid from #temp1 
     where rownumber = 1) F1, 
    (select factorvalue from #temp1 
     where rownumber = 1) V1,
    (select factorid from #temp1 
     where rownumber = 2) F2, 
    (select factorvalue from #temp1 
     where rownumber = 2) V2
from 
    #temp1
group by 
    StorageTicketI
```

Here is the output:

```
ID  F1  V1  F2  V2
--------------------
23  116 90  210 13.2
```

Comment: Can you show the sample data that resulted in your sample result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simple conditional aggregation in concert with Row_Number() may do the trick

```
Select StorageTicketID
      ,F1 = max(case when RN=1 then FactorID    else null end)
      ,V1 = max(case when RN=1 then FactorValue else null end)
      ,F2 = max(case when RN=2 then FactorID    else null end)
      ,V2 = max(case when RN=2 then FactorValue else null end)
 From  (
        Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By StorageTicketID Order By (Select NULL))
         From  YourTable
       ) A
 Group By StorageTicketID
```

Returns

```
StorageTicketID F1    V1      F2    V2
23              116   90.00   210   13.20
```

> **Edit - Just for fun a I added a Dynamic version**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = (Select ',F'+RN+' = max(case when RN='+RN+' then FactorID else null end),V'+RN+' = max(case when RN='+RN+' then FactorValue else null end)' From (Select Distinct RN=cast(Row_Number() over (Partition By StorageTicketID Order By (Select null)) as varchar(15)) from YourTable) A Order by 1 For XML Path(''))
Select  @SQL = '
Select StorageTicketID'+@SQL+'
 From  (
        Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By StorageTicketID Order By (Select NULL))
         From  YourTable
       ) A
 Group By StorageTicketID
'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a PIVOT on a derived table that is filtered the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on John's input I went with

```
Select StorageTicketID
      ,F1 = max(case when RN=1 then FactorID    else null end)
      ,V1 = max(case when RN=1 then FactorValue else null end)
      ,F2 = max(case when RN=2 then FactorID    else null end)
      ,V2 = max(case when RN=2 then FactorValue else null end)
 From  (
        Select st.StorageTicketID,glfr.FactorID, glfr.FactorValue,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By StorageTicketID Order By (Select NULL))
         From  storageticket st
         join GrainLoadFactorResult glfr on st.StorageTicketID = glfr.ParentID
       ) A
 Group By StorageTicketID
```

I am just posting this as I thought it might be helpful to show the join.